# How to use PHP variable in href?

Tags: php, html

I made a FacebookConnect class in PHP for a project. It's working well, but the  problem is that I'm unable to use the `href` correctly.

```
<a href="index.php?module=compte&action=loginFacebook" class="fb-login-button">Connect with fb</a>
```

I'm trying to call a method from one of my controllers in the `href`. I want to make it so that when I click on the button, it starts the login process.

```
public function _loginFacebook()
{
    $connect = new FacebookConnect($appid,$app_secret);

    $user = $connect->connect('http://localhost/washare/?site=public&module=Compte&action=profil');

    if (is_string($user)) {
        return $user;
    }
}
```

In fact, I wanted to use the `$user` variable (which is a redirect URL) in the `href` directly, but iI guess I'm doing this wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: So where exactly do you want to put the `$user` variable? There are some pieces missing from your example and it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use the $user variable in the href to trigger directly the redirect url on the click on the button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Function _loginFacebook is called? If so, what part of code is achieved?
You can use header for redirecting on php.

```
<?php    
header('Location: mapeamento.php');    
?>
```